# Should I always dispose subscriptions of observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Should I always dispose observables when the `ViewModel` automatically goes out of scope and no reference to other classes is maintained?

A little example:

```
public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new ReactiveList<string>();
        MyList.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

        //Do I have to dispose/unsubscribe this?
        MyList.ItemChanged.Subscribe(_ => ...);

        //Or this?
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyList).Subscribe(_ => ...);
    }

    ReactiveList<string> _myList;
    public ReactiveList<string> MyList
    {
        get => _myList;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _myList, value);
    }
}
```

From my understanding the subscriptions are plain .NET objects. With no reference outside of the `ViewModel` class. So when my `TestViewModel` goes out of scope (i.e. the `object` is never used anymore and replaced with another one) the `GarbageCollector` should cleanup all the stuff inside the ViewModel, so I have **not** to manually call `Dispose` on the returned `IDisposables`.

Am I correct here?

**Edit**
The `ReactiveList` could also hold other .NET objects. This example is not specific to the immutable string type.

Comment: Who knows what schedulers get involved and what subscriptions might be hanging on to your `ViewModel`? You should always dispose a disposable. It is simply a good programming practice.

Comment: But the [ReactiveUiDocs](https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/dispose-your-subscriptions) says that not every `Subscription` needs to be disposed?

Comment: I agree, not every subscription needs to be disposed. Not every `IDisposable` needs to be disposed. But it's very hard to always know which ones must be. All I'm saying is that you can't be sure that you're not leaving a subscription open that is holding on to resources. If you do a join or a query involving any concurrency then you're holding on to timers. You don't know how your clients are using your observables. It's just good practice to dispose. Always.

Comment: The RxUI guys disagree, Kent Boogart in particular who has found it can tank performance especially on mobile if you Dispose everything.

Comment: To quote his book, You I And ReactiveUI.

"Is it necessary? To answer this question, you need to consider the object chain established by each subscription. If nothing in that chain is rooted, it will not prevent objects from being collected." In your question nothing (except the ReactiveList is exposed) is rooted beyond the current class, WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyList) simplify subscribes to the current object's INotifyPropertyChanged and is local only in Subscribe, the ItemChanged is local and acts on a Immutable items.  The only possible issue is your ReactiveList and outside subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Kent Boogart (one of the ReactiveUI maintainers) opinion on the matter:

So, hypothetically...if you're using `WhenActivated` in a view, when do you dispose of the disposable that it returns? You'd have to store it in a local field and make the view disposable. But then who disposes of the view? You'd need platform hooks to know when an appropriate time to dispose it is - not a trivial matter if that view is reused in virtualization scenarios. So there's that.

And what about when you execute a reactive command? Do you store off the disposable you get so you can "clean it up" later? I'm gonna guess not, and for good reason. When the execution completes, all observers are auto-unsubscribed anyway. Generally, subscriptions to pipelines that have a finite lifetime (eg. via a timeout) need not be disposed manually. Disposing of such a subscription is about as useful as disposing of a `MemoryStream`.

In addition to this, I have found that reactive code in VMs in particular tends to juggle a lot of disposables. Storing all those disposables away and attempting disposal tends to clutter the code and force the VM itself to be disposable, further confusing matters. Perf is another factor to consider, particularly on Android.

So my advice stems from all this. I find that calling out those subscriptions that *require* disposal by wrapping them in `WhenActivated` is the most pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

To answer questions like these for your specific case, you'll have to use the diagnostic tools to figure out what works in your case.

One test run with the `using` block and one without:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //warmup types
        var vm = new TestViewModel();

        Console.ReadLine(); //Snapshot #1
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            Model();

        GC.Collect();
        Console.ReadLine();  //Snapshot #2
    }

    private static void Model()
    {
        using (var vm = new TestViewModel())
        {                
        }
    }
}
```

No manual dispose:

[image: No disposal]

Both subscriptions disposed:

[image: Both subscriptions disposed]

For 1k iterations, the differences are minor and GC is doing its job.
The differences are mostly `WeakReference` types.

Ultimately, as Glenn Watson says, you have to decide on a case by case basis. Observables which use periodic scheduling are a good candidate for disposing manually.

[ReactiveUI Guidelines for when to dispose subscriptions](https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/dispose-your-subscriptions)

Comment: Kent Boogart has a chapter in his book, You I And ReactiveUI, why always "Disposing" subscriptions like this is a BAD idea especially on mobile. You have to be smart where you use it.

Comment: Essentially your going to tank performance big time. In fact even the documentation warns against over disposing https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/dispose-your-subscriptions

Comment: @GlennWatson Noted. I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on the garbage collector to dispose your object cleanly.

Finalizers have a maximum execution time and may be executed in any order, and `Dispose` will not even be called if the Disposing pattern is properly implemented.

`Dispose` should clean up managed resources and finalizers should clean up unmanaged resources to avoid memory leaks. The `Disposing(bool)` pattern will call both on explicit `Dispose`, and only unmanaged on garbage collection.

Explicit `Dispose` also allows you to clean up earlier, rather than waiting until the GC collects.

Specifically for subscriptions, event handlers, etc not clearing references can mean that when the GC does collect, references still exist, in which case the object would not be collected at all.

If you know there are no paths to root, you may not strictly have to explicitly dispose, but often in this case someone comes along later and accidentally keeps a reference to one object in the graph and before you know it, the whole graph can never be collected.

Comment: The GC doesn't ever call `.Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects. Never. However, it may call a finalizer and a finalizer may call `.Dispose()`. Unless you inspect the source code of every `IDisposable` you use you never know if it might.

Comment: I didn't say the GC calls `Dispose()` at all. If the dispose pattern is implemented properly, the finalizer should not dispose of managed objects. `Dispose` calls `Dispose(true)`, which disposes both managed and unmanaged resources, and suppresses the finalizer. The finalizer calls `Dispose(false)`, which only disposes of unmanaged resources. You should still call `Dispose()` when using this, but if you forget, the finalizer should at least prevent unmanaged memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, agreed. It works as long as the finalizer is implemented properly.