# ReactiveUI WhenActivated throws ObjectDisposedException on Android

Tags: reactiveui

We're currently experiencing an issue with `WhenActivated` with version 8 unward.  We aren't using the routing infrastructure and are rather using an in house MVVM framework.  In order to support `ISupportActivation` we listening to the `OnAppearing` and `OnDisapearing` events in a base page and manually calling `Activate()` and `Deactivate()`.

The following used to work in the Alpha version of version 8 but isn't any longer.  No issues in iOS.

The code below illustrate that issue, a single ReactiveCommand is bound on the MainPage and we navigate to a Target hello world page. A repo can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/vertexapex/rxbug)

### BaseContentPage

```
using System;
using ReactiveBug.ViewModels;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.XamForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReactiveBug.Pages
{
    public class BaseContentPage<T> : ReactiveContentPage<T> where T : ReactiveBaseModel
    {
        public BaseContentPage()
        {
            this.Events().Appearing.Subscribe(args =>
            {
                if (ViewModel is ISupportsActivation activation)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Activating {GetType().Name}");

                    activation.Activator?.Activate();
                }
            });

            this.Events().Disappearing.Subscribe(args =>
            {
                if (ViewModel is ISupportsActivation activation)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Deactivating {GetType().Name}");

                    activation.Activator.Deactivate();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### MainPage VM (blank page with label bound to a command)

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ReactiveBug.Pages;
using ReactiveUI;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReactiveBug.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ReactiveBaseModel
    {
        private ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> _labelClickCommand;

        public MainPageViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base(navigation)
        {
            this.WhenActivated(d => { d(RxSetupLabelClickCommand()); });
        }

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> LabelClickCommand
        {
            get => _labelClickCommand;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _labelClickCommand, value);
        }

        private async Task InternalLabelClickCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(InternalLabelClickCommand)}");

            var p = new TargetPage();
            var vm = new TargetPageViewModel(p.Navigation);

            p.ViewModel = vm;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(p);
        }

        private IDisposable RxSetupLabelClickCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(RxSetupLabelClickCommand)}");

            LabelClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(InternalLabelClickCommand);

            LabelClickCommand
                .IsExecuting
                .Subscribe(isExecuting => Console.Write($"{nameof(LabelClickCommand)}.IsExecuting: {isExecuting}"));

            LabelClickCommand
                .ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(exception =>
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error executing {nameof(LabelClickCommand)}.  Ex: {exception.ToString()}"));

            return LabelClickCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Running this on Android leads to the following exception stack trace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
  at System.Reactive.DisposedObserver`1[T].OnNext (T value) [0x00000] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1[T].OnNext (T value) [0x00000] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.SynchronizedObserver`1[T].OnNextCore (T value) [0x00011] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.ObserverBase`1[T].OnNext (T value) [0x0000d] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject+AnonymousSubject`2[T,U].OnNext (T value) [0x00000] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`2[TParam,TResult].<Execute>b__17_3 () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\src\ReactiveUI\ReactiveCommand.cs:860 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Finally`1+_+<>c__DisplayClass2_0[TSource].<Run>b__0 () [0x0000d] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Disposables.AnonymousDisposable.Dispose () [0x00010] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.set_Disposable (System.IDisposable value) [0x00028] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].SubscribeRaw (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.Boolean enableSafeguard) [0x0009a] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.ObservableExtensions.SubscribeSafe[T] (System.IObservable`1[T] source, System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x00036] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1[TSource].Run (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.IDisposable cancel, System.Action`1[T] setSink) [0x0000f] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].SubscribeRaw (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.Boolean enableSafeguard) [0x00071] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.ObservableExtensions.SubscribeSafe[T] (System.IObservable`1[T] source, System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x00036] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Subjects.ConnectableObservable`2[TSource,TResult].Connect () [0x00019] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1+_[TSource].Run () [0x00053] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1[TSource].Run (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.IDisposable cancel, System.Action`1[T] setSink) [0x00010] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].SubscribeRaw (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.Boolean enableSafeguard) [0x00071] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.ObservableExtensions.SubscribeSafe[T] (System.IObservable`1[T] source, System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x00036] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ObserveOn`1[TSource].Run (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.IDisposable cancel, System.Action`1[T] setSink) [0x00034] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].SubscribeRaw (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.Boolean enableSafeguard) [0x00071] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.ObservableExtensions.SubscribeSafe[T] (System.IObservable`1[T] source, System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x00036] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.TailRecursiveSink`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x00194] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.AsyncLock.Wait (System.Action action) [0x000d0] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.TailRecursiveSink`1[TSource].<Run>b__7_0 (System.Action self) [0x00007] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler+<>c.<Schedule>b__47_0 (System.Action`1[T] _action, System.Action`1[T] self) [0x00014] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler+<>c__DisplayClass49_0`1[TState].<InvokeRec1>b__0 (TState state1) [0x0001e] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.InvokeRec1[TState] (System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler, System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler+Pair`2[T1,T2] pair) [0x0004a] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`3[System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler,System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler+Pair`2[System.Action`1[System.Action],System.Action`2[System.Action`1[System.Action],System.Action`1[System.Action`1[System.Action]]]],System.IDisposable].invoke_TResult_T1_T2(System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler,System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler/Pair`2<System.Action`1<System.Action>, System.Action`2<System.Action`1<System.Action>, System.Action`1<System.Action`1<System.Action>>>>)
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ImmediateScheduler.Schedule[TState] (TState state, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action) [0x00014] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Schedule[TState] (System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler, TState state, System.Action`2[T1,T2] action) [0x00042] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Schedule (System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler, System.Action`1[T] action) [0x0001c] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.TailRecursiveSink`1[TSource].Run (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sources) [0x00068] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Catch`1[TSource].Run (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.IDisposable cancel, System.Action`1[T] setSink) [0x0000f] in <e9c1ccec51844dbd92b833a0b4bc960e>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].Run (System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler _, System.Reactive.Producer`1+State[TSource] x) [0x00000] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`2[TAbsolute,TValue].InvokeCore () [0x00000] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`1[TAbsolute].Invoke () [0x0000d] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler+Trampoline.Run (System.Reactive.Concurrency.SchedulerQueue`1[TAbsolute] queue) [0x00040] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule[TState] (TState state, System.TimeSpan dueTime, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action) [0x00046] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.LocalScheduler.Schedule[TState] (TState state, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action) [0x0000e] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].SubscribeRaw (System.IObserver`1[T] observer, System.Boolean enableSafeguard) [0x0005c] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Producer`1[TSource].Subscribe (System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x0000e] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe[T] (System.IObservable`1[T] source) [0x00023] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 Unhandled Exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.


   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommandBase`2[TParam,TResult].ICommandExecute (System.Object parameter) [0x00048] in D:\a\1\s\src\ReactiveUI\ReactiveCommand.cs:721 
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\src\ReactiveUI\ReactiveCommand.cs:622 
   at Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.SendTapped (Xamarin.Forms.View sender) [0x00018] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TapGestureRecognizer.cs:44 
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TapGestureHandler.OnTap (System.Int32 count) [0x00028] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\TapGestureHandler.cs:37 
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.InnerGestureListener.Android.Views.GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener.OnSingleTapUp (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00014] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\InnerGestureListener.cs:140 
   at Android.Views.GestureDetector+IOnGestureListenerInvoker.n_OnSingleTapUp_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x0000f] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.81a6100d-59c5-43e9-a3f0-6c38c921f2aa(intptr,intptr,intptr)
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.81a6100d-59c5-43e9-a3f0-6c38c921f2aa(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a(intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*)
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00073] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
  at Android.Views.GestureDetector.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent ev) [0x00031] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.GestureManager+TapAndPanGestureDetector.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent ev) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\GestureManager.cs:87 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.GestureManager.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x0005c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\GestureManager.cs:59 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:38
```

Anyone has any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer one of the two questions.

> how to fix this?

I've seen a lot of ReactiveUI projects but never see anyone dispose of ReactiveCommands. The important thing to remember is to dispose of ReactiveCommand subscriptions and bindings.

So if you choose to bind the ReactiveUI way, rather than via xaml, you could do the following in xaml:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="TapGesture" />
```

and in the MainPage constructor:

```
this.WhenActivated(
    disposables =>
    {
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.LabelClickCommand, v => v.TapGesture.Command)
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    });
```

and in the ViewModel just dispose of any extra subscriptions:

```
public MainPageViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base(navigation)
{
    LabelClickCommand = ReactiveCommand
        .CreateFromTask(InternalLabelClickCommand);

    this.WhenActivated(
        disposables =>
        {
            LabelClickCommand
                .IsExecuting
                .Subscribe(isExecuting => Console.Write($"{nameof(LabelClickCommand)}.IsExecuting: {isExecuting}"))
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            LabelClickCommand
                .ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(exception =>
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error executing {nameof(LabelClickCommand)}. Ex: {exception.ToString()}"))
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
}
```

I tested this code, so it works as expected.

In your solution I suspect that LabelClickCommand was being disposed of *before* it finished executing; because I put a breakpoint at the closing brace after the await statement but it was never hit.

But then again, you said it works fine in iOS, and in the Alpha version of ReactiveUI 8, so I'm not sure.

Sorry for not having an explanation, in that regard. Hopefully, someone else can chime in. Until then, I hope this alternative approach fits your needs.

**Update**

As Glenn mentioned in the comments,

> Rx in general you don't want to necessarily dispose of everything (more vital on Mobile Apps for sure) due to performance issues.

Scope determines if you need to bother disposing of subscriptions. Here's another [SO answer that mentions this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002182/5984310).

As an example, you would definitely want to dispose of the following subscription, especially if the service has a full app lifetime. Otherwise, the service would continue holding on to that subscription after the view model has been destroyed.

```
_someSubscription = someService
    .SomePipeline
    .Subscribe(x => ...);
```

In contrast, the subscriptions to ThrownExceptions and IsExecuting of LabelClickCommand have local scope, so you don't even really need to dispose of those, as I did above.

Comment: This makes sense.  We always dispose of disposables (hence we disposed the ReactiveCommand).  As we started embracing WhenActivated and CompositeDisposable we disposed of the ReactiveCommand there out of convenience.

Looking back on it, am I correct to say that the IDisposable of the ReactiveCommand is really only a mean to the reactive fluent interface for subscription and doesn't really need being disposed of?

Comment: It can be useful in very limited scenarios, Rx in general you don't want to necessarily dispose of everything (more vital on Mobile Apps for sure) due to performance issues. Essentially if a subscription doesn't access outside objects the GC will take of the cleaning up the subscription for you. Here's where another StackOverflow article that might be handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829345/should-i-always-dispose-subscriptions-of-observables/50829684#50829684
Also worth noting one of the maintainers of the RxUI project wrote a book with a section about disposing Kent Boogart.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @GlennWatson . Adding it to the answer.